# After rigging character model flips to the base of the skeleton

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

After I parent the bones to the character, the character model flips and is placed down instead of staying in position. See screenshots for reference:

Before applying rig:

[image]

After applying rig:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. I tried using different options for weights but all of them result in the model flipping.

For added context, the model was created in Vroid and converted to fbx. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you applied Scale, Rotation, and Location (Ctrl+A in Object mode) to the armature and the object before you have parented them?

Comment: Hello, I tried changing the location settings of the object to match those of the armature but the flipping still happens

Comment: Ah never mind, thank you, I fixed it after applying the location properly